# html2canvas won't work in asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, html2canvas

I have been told that the code used below for jquery looks fine but am still baffled why I cannot get html2canvas to work.  I am not getting any response when the button is clicked.  I have tried other methods with the button and they work fine.  Can anyone please advise where I may be going wrong?

The jquery I have is:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#Print_Button').click(function () {
         html2canvas($('#form1'),{
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
            cvs = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            window.open(cvs)
        }
    });
    });
 });
```

and the HTML is:

```
<table id="table_1"">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style12">MCN Ref No.</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ReadOnly="True" runat="server" Width="116px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style12">Date:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" ReadOnly="True" runat="server" Width="116px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style12">Time:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="116px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<img alt="Logo" class="auto-style10" src="logo.png" /><div id ="form">
<table id="main_table" class = "table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style8">SITE:</td>
        <td class="auto-style9">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox6_TextChanged" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style4">HAULIER(CARRIER):</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style8">DESCRIPTION OF WASTE:</td>
        <td class="auto-style9">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style4">DESTINATION:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style8">EWC CODE:</td>
        <td class="auto-style9">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style4">VEHICLE REGISTRATION:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style8">QUANTITY:</td>
        <td class="auto-style9">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style4">DRIVER NAME:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style8">NOMINAL WEIGHT:</td>
        <td class="auto-style9">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style4">SKIP ID:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox16" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>


    <table id="table_2" style="width:30%;">
        <tr>
            <td>DUTY OF CARE:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox14_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<p id="tsandcs">

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because $ is [JQuery selector.](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp). If you don't use jquery `$('#Print_Button')` returns *null*. You subscribe to *null onclick* event instead of button. If you want your code works without jquery you should change  `$('#')` to javascricpt [getbyId](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp) `document.getElementById("")`

At the end your code has to look like

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
     document.getElementById("Print_Button").click(function () {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("form1"),{
           onrendered: function(canvas) {
           cvs = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
           window.open(cvs)
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Max Mokrousov, thank you for amending this for me, I am new to Javascript.  I have ran the code, but for some reason the only thing that happens is that the page continously refreshes?  I only know that as I have a timestamp in c# on one of the tables cells.

Comment: @kehoewex86 I can't see what's wrong. I don't see Print_Button and form1 in your html.  Update page as you see in your browser with html input elements instead of asp:TextBox. Only than I can say you something.